# Need wp rest api for featured video post

Tags: rest-api

hi i very new to rest api...I'm using WP REST API V2 in my project. After sending Get request to get posts, I don't see fields with the source of my audio/video wordpress posts (youtube or soundcloud sources)

im trying use many api like
wp-json/wp/v2/media
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed
wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?video_url

i dont know how to fix this..pls anyone help me to fix this..
[image]

i can able to get only featured image for tat video post..could not able to play video..

Comment: Is this a custom post type with a video_url field? You'd need to [register the field for the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47636830/243245). Or a regular post with a YouTube URL in it that gets turned into a player with oEmbeded?

Comment: its a custom post video

Answer (score 0):

You have a custom post type called 'video' with a video_url field. You need to call [register_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/) in the [rest_api_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_api_init/) hook to get the API to return this field, e.g.

```
function register_post_meta_video_video_url( $wp_rest_server ) {
    register_post_meta( 'video', 'video_url', array(
        'type'         => 'string',
        'description'  => 'Featured video URL',
        'single'       => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    ) );
};
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_post_meta_video_video_url', 10, 1 );
```

See [REST API Modifying Responses](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#post-type-specific-meta).

Comment: In which file i needs to add this code.. In funtion.php?

Comment: Yes, in functions.php in a custom plugin. (Or possibly functions.php in a custom theme too, but I'm not sure the wp-admin site actually loads the theme?)

Comment: Thankq Rup ..i got a solutions for tis...Could u ls help me to get related post, related video post api...